# I need to remove an IBOUTLET Connection that causes a crash

Tags: iphone, xcode

Where are IBOUTLET Connections are stored?
How can I remove a connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Interface Builder, right click on the "Files Owner".  If you have a bad connection, it will show up with a yellow mark next to it - just hit the "X" to delete.